How to get the MAC address of my local network interface by win socket or remote ip
Is there a way to get the MAC address (physical address) of my network interface, through which the socket connection passes, having win socket and remote ip.
That is, we have a SOCKET through which we connect to a remote server, and we need to find out which network interface my local machine is connected to and which MAC it has. Not remote MAC.
In a situation where we have 2 or more network interfaces, we cannot reliably understand that the connection was made using the main adapter.
We have ifreq and <arpa/inet.h> on Linux - Finding MAC address from IP address
But I couldn't find a similar solution under Windows
Where do I get arpa/inet.h?
We have https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-getsockopt with SOL_SOCKET with SO_PROTOCOL_INFO. But it's not.
We have IPX_ADDRESS but we use TCP/IP
A READY solution:
std::vector<int> find_mac_by_in_ip(const std::string& in_ip); // function body is below

int main()
{
    SOCKET pRSocket = some_socket;

    sockaddr_storage optVal;
    int optLen = sizeof(sockaddr_storage);
    std::string interface_ip;

    if (getsockname(pRSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&optVal, &optLen) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "\n---\n";

        char in_ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]; 

        if (optVal.ss_family == AF_INET) {
            sockaddr_in* addr_in = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(&optVal);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), in_ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        }
        else if (optVal.ss_family == AF_INET6) {
            sockaddr_in6* addr_in6 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(&optVal);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), in_ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        }
        else {
            // TODO
        }
        interface_ip = in_ip;

        std::cout << in_ip << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\n";

    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n Error socket Connect() " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    }

    if (interface_ip == "::1")
    {
    }
    else if (optVal.ss_family == AF_INET6)
    {
    }
    else if (optVal.ss_family == AF_INET)
    {
        auto res = find_mac_by_in_ip(interface_ip);
        for (auto i : res)
        {
            std::cout << std::hex << i << " "; // we have mac 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

std::vector<int> find_mac_by_in_ip(const std::string& in_ip)
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = NULL;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    UINT i;

    /* variables used to print DHCP time info */
    struct tm newtime;
    char buffer[32];
    errno_t error;

    ULONG ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
        return {};
    }
    // Make an initial call to GetAdaptersInfo to get
    // the necessary size into the ulOutBufLen variable
    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        free(pAdapterInfo);
        pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)malloc(ulOutBufLen);
        if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
            return {};
        }
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {
        pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
        while (pAdapter) {
            if (in_ip == pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String)
            {
                std::vector<int> ret_mac;
                ret_mac.reserve(6);
                for (i = 0; i < pAdapter->AddressLength; i++) {
                        ret_mac.push_back((int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
                }
                if (pAdapterInfo)
                    free(pAdapterInfo);
                return ret_mac;
            }

            pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
            // printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("GetAdaptersInfo failed with error: %d\n", dwRetVal);

    }
    if (pAdapterInfo)
        free(pAdapterInfo);
    return {};
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

GetAdaptersAddresses to query NIC information. Use the PhysicalAddress field in the struct.

@Mestkon In a situation where we have 2 or more network interfaces, we cannot reliably understand that the connection was made using the main adapter

@Superlokkus The thing is, I don't have any code that can do this.

How do you define "the main adapter"? Is it the route through with 0.0.0.0/8 is routed? or maybe your company VPN? Can you do the usual trick of opening a UDP socket (without sending any data) and querying the local IP address, and resolving the MAC address from there?

@Botje The main adapter is the main network interface of my computer.
And how can we "from there" identify the local mac if our mac only sees the nearest router/gateway

@Akri Your computer does not have a "main network interface". GetAdaptersAddresses gives you information about ALL adapters available on your machine.

@Akri That question gets really muddy once you factor in VPNs. Your "main network interface" might still be the wired/wifi adapter, but the interface actually used to present to the VPN will be the VPN adapter. With a bogus MAC address.

@Botje the main thing for me is to get this MAC, since the network environment should not change in a working system.
And the question of which MAC will be taken with VPN enabled is very interesting. I'll try to find out

And then there's even more fun stuff like split routing, where your VPN adapter might only put itself as the default for the company network space (eg 10/8) but let other connections go through the actual network interface. All to say: "default network interface" is a very muddy concept and really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

@Botje In fact, I need that network interface through which we connect somewhere

does that "somewhere" have a name or IP address? If so, see the UDP socket trick above.

The only time I needed to have the MAC address was to figure out which physical connection was having connectivity problems.  (Turned out the cable was bad and the NIC was bad.)

If you have a connected (or bound) socket, you can call getsockname() to find out the socket's local IP address.
Once you have the socket's local IP address, all you need to do is figure out which local NIC is associated with that IP address, and then find out the MAC address associated with that local NIC.
As Mestkon mentioned in his comment, you can call GetAdaptersAddresses() to obtain information about the local NICs, then it's just a matter of looking through the returned structs to find the specific values you are interested in; e.g. for the MAC address you want the PhysicalAddress field of the PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES associated with your IP address.
If you'd like to see some example code that does this sort of thing, take a look at lines 1993-2092 of this file (that I wrote as part of my networking library); in particular look at the way the local variable mac is set at line 2067, to contain the MAC address of a local NIC.

Thank you very much <3.
I'll publish the code a little later
